# How to repeatedly call a function after a certain amount of time

Tags: java

I want to make a function that will be called after certain amount of time. Also, this should be repeated after the same amount of time. For example, the function may be called every 60 seconds.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11434143/3514144

Answer (score 10):

Using `java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()` and `java.util.TimerTask` is a possible solution:

```
Timer t = new Timer();

t.scheduleAtFixedRate(
    new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    },
    0,      // run first occurrence immediatetly
    2000)); // run every two seconds
```

Comment: good, although javax.swing.timer may be a better choice if Fisol Rasel is using lots of Swing components

Answer (score 10):

In order to call a method repeatedly you need to use some form of threading that runs in the background. I recommend using [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html):

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                // code to execute repeatedly
           }
       }, 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // execute every 60 seconds
```

Comment: @VNJ: No, the worker threads cannot exist if the parent process is killed.

Comment: Then how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

Swing Timer is also good idea to implement repeatedly function calls.

```
Timer t = new Timer(0, null);

t.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          //do something
    }
});

t.setRepeats(true);
t.setDelay(1000); //1 sec
t.start();
```