# java- Calling a function at every interval

Tags: java

I have a program where I am able to insert a filepath and it's corresponding parameters to a table.

After that, I have another function called `do_Scan()`
that scans the table and do some processing and indexing to it.

However, I want this function `do_Scan()` to be run at certain intervals, say every N minutes then it will call this function. The N is definitely configurable.

I was thinking of using a timer class but not quite sure how to implement the configuration. The idea is I create a Timer function that will call the `do_Scan` method.

The class should be something like this:

```
public void schedule(TimerTask task,long delay,long period){

}
```

My main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Indexing test= new Indexing();
    java.sql.Timestamp date = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
    // Exception e=e.printStackTrace();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a file path: ");
    System.out.flush();
    String filename = scanner.nextLine();
    File file = new File(filename);
    if(file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {
        test.index_request(filename,"Active",date,date,"");
    }else{
        test.index_request(filename,"Error",date,date,"Some errorCode");
    }

    // Call schedule() function 
}}
```

How do I setup the Timer class so it runs indefinitely for certain interval?

Comment: Example? But i want the Timer to be in it's own function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416242/how-to-repeatedly-call-a-function-after-a-certain-amount-of-time see if this may helps you

Comment: yes it does help. is this the best way to accomplish?

Comment: The answers suggesting `Runnable` are pretty old. Use lambdas instead (since java 1.8).

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is using a class which is a part of standard library.

```
java.util.Timer
```

Here is a simple example of using it:

```
import java.util.Timer; 
import java.util.TimerTask; 

class MyTask extends TimerTask 
{ 
   public static int i = 0; 
   public void run() 
   { 
      System.out.println("Hello, I'm timer, running iteration: " + ++i); 
   } 
} 

public class Test 
{ 
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   { 

      Timer timer = new Timer(); 
      TimerTask task = new MyTask(); 

      timer.schedule(task, 2000, 5000);  // 2000 - delay (can set to 0 for immediate execution), 5000 is a frequency.

   } 
}
```

Comment: What about if there is any error occur in there, then I need to write another function to handle it.

Comment: Yes, sure, but it's your custom logic and depends on the application. Timer only gives an ability to run something periodically. It doesn't save you from handling errors

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`:

Let's assume you have a task method:

```
public void task(String foo, Integer bar){
    // ...
}
```

**Before Java 1.8**

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(2);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        task(fooParam, barParam);  
    }
}, 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

**Java 1.8+**

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> task(fooParam, barParam), 0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Why did you choose 2 as the Poolsize in the before Java 1.8 example?

Answer (score 0):

To do that I recommend you to use Java's `ScheduledExecutorService` which provides you with an API to schedule tasks at fixed rate (among other APIs).

You have 2 options to do that:

1. Implementing `Runnable` or `Callable` (or the like) in your task and call the `schedule()` method:

   ```
   public class IndexingTask implements Runnable {

       @Override
       public void run() {
           schedule();
       }

       private void schedule() {
           //do something
       }
   }



   public static void main(String[] args) {
       //do some stuff
       long delay = getDelay();
       ScheduledExecutorService scheduledThreadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
       scheduledThreadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(new IndexingTask(), 0, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   }
   ```
2. Using Lambda expression to do that inline:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       //do some stuff
       long delay = getDelay();
       ScheduledExecutorService scheduledThreadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
       scheduledThreadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> doSomething(), 0, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   }
   ```

If you're using Spring Framework, you can simply use the `@Scheduled` annotation as follows:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
public void schedule() {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There're many ways to solve this issue. I think that the simpliest way, when you use this approach in given place only and do not use external frameworks like Spring:

```
private void runWithInterval(long millis) {
    Runnable task = () -> {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(millis);
                // payload
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();
}
```

To call it with 1 minute interval:

> runWithInterval(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1));

**P.S.**

Another ways details you can see in other posts here:

- `@Scheduler` annotation when using `Spring`
- Using thread pool with single thread: `ScheduledExecutorService scheduledThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)`
- Using `Timer`: `new Timer().schedule(new Runnable() {}, TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1))`

Comment: This approach leads to drift since the payload affects the timing.

Comment: `Thread.sleep` will take the thread and thereby wasting a precious thread doing nothing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with [ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io/) there is java library called [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) which can be used as:

```
Flowable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Or any other desired interval
        .subscribe(iteration -> System.out.println("Hello, I'm timer, running iteration: " + iteration));
```

But you really should read more about this approach and library